# Как правильно реализовать работу в двух ветках

Tags: git, github

Хочу в ветку **main** пушить весь проект, а ветку **gh-pages** только папку **src**.
Как это правильно сделать?
Нашёл [вот такое](https://nicothin.pro/page/gh-pages) решение, вроде работает, но можно ли как-то проще это всё реализовать?
Вообще было бы идеально, чтоб при пуше в **main** менялось сразу и в **gh-pages**.

Comment: Вынести не относящее к src в отдельный репозиторий.

Comment: Если это самое удобное решение, тогда грустно.

Comment: Как я понял, вы сделали коммит, который содержит в себе изменения как в коде, так и в `src`. Все из этого коммита должно попасть в ветку `main`, а в `gh-pages` - только из src? Если да, то есть 2 способа: 1. Изменения в `src` коммитить только в ветке gh-pages, а в main переносить через merge или cherry-pick. 2. Коммитить в main, затем переключаться на gh-pages, и мержить/черипикать БЕЗ коммита (ключики `--no-commit --no-ff`). Удалять ненужное (а можно сделать хитрый .gitignore для разных веток). Коммитить

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите src в отдельный репозиторий и подключайте его в проект в качестве [подмодуля](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8).